# Pass eval and span id from gridview to javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm trying to pass a value and span id to a JavaScript function. I think I have the value set right but I'm having problems passing the span.
This is a nested gridview so I can't see the control and need to send it to the function.

## In GridView

```
 <input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0}); Eval("TimeMinutes.ClientID")%>' value="Start" id="Start" />
 <input type="button" value="Stop" id="Stop" />
 <input type="text" value='<%#Eval("FormulaTiming")%>' id="TimeMinutes" />
 <span id="CountDown"></span>
```

## JavaScript Function

```
var interval;
 
  function countdown(minutes, spanid) {
      interval = setInterval(function () {
          var lbl = document.getElementById(element);
          if (seconds == 0) {
              if (minutes == 0) {
                  el.innerHTML = "countdown's over!";
                  clearInterval(interval);
                  return;
              } else {
                  minutes--;
                  seconds = 60;
              }
          }
          if (minutes > 0) {
              var minute_text = minutes + (minutes > 1 ? ' minutes' : ' minute');
          } else {
              var minute_text = '';
          }
          var second_text = seconds > 1 ? 'seconds' : 'second';
          el.innerHTML = minute_text + ' ' + seconds + ' ' + second_text + ' remaining';
          seconds--;
      }, 1000);
  }
```

I am still trying to figure out how to change the script, but first I need to pass the eval and span.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please show what the generated HTML for `<input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0}); Eval("TimeMinutes.ClientID")%>' value="Start" id="Start" />` is. You seem to be missing one of the quotes around "countdown({0})"

Comment: I receive the error... Comma, ')', or a valid expression continuation expected.  On... <input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0}); Eval("TimeMinutes.ClientID")%>' value="Start" id="Start" />

Comment: Like I said, your quotes are mismatched

Comment: I Took out passing the span id and just included the eval and I receive no error.                 
<input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0});")%>' value="Start" id="Start" />
How would I add the span id to the onclick function.  Also there is no HTML generated for these controls.  It is in a nested grid.

Comment: I don't understand how there could be no generated HTML for the control. If you view source and search for `id="Start"`, you should find the generated HTML

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  The HTML is 
 <input type="button" onclick='countdown(20);' value="Start" id="Start" />
                <input type="button" value="Stop" id="Stop" />

                <input type="text" value='20' id="TimeMinutes" />
                  <span id="CountDown"></span>

Comment: I haven't got many answers.  I have tried to figure out how to get to my questions, to see if there are any answers, but can't find them, Once I close the page.  I always want to accept an answer and will try harder to find my questions from now on.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here's the list of questions you asked: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1420532/sheri-trager?tab=questions The questions that have the word `answer` in white in a green box are the ones that you haven't accepted an answer for. Also, did you not like the answer I gave you? If you did, you should upvote it also to give me some more rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following asp.net code

```
<input type="button" onclick='<%# Eval("FormulaTiming", "countdown({0}, \"Start\"); %>' value="Start" id="Start" />
```

Should yield the following HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick='countdown(20, "Start");' value="Start" id="Start" />
```